# Using "set" in cocoa method name

Tags: cocoa, naming-conventions

In my class, I have:

```
@property (atomic, retain) NSPredicate* predicate;
```

So obviously setPredicate:somePredicate works.

I want a class method that looks like:

```
-(void)setPredicateWithDate:(NSDate *)date
{
   NSPredicate* predicate = (build a predicate with the NSDate)

   [self setPredicate:predicate];
}
```

This seems to conflict with Cocoa's naming conventions because I do not have a property called predicateWithDate. What do folks usually name these sort of methods?

I was thinking "applyPredicateWithDate:"

Thoughts?

Comment: `NSView` has methods like `setFrameOrigin:` and `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`.

Answer (score 2):

Naming a method that starts with `set` is absolutely fine. Not all methods that start with `set` has to be a setter directly to the instance variable named after set, it should just do what it says and change the ivars in your class accordingly, in which your case is perfectly fine.